# Is it safe to modify sources in repository while git svn dcommit is in progress?

Tags: git

I have a big repository and `git svn dcommit` takes pretty big time.

Will my repo be in consistent state if I'll modify sources (without any git operations) while dcommit is in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd advise against making changes while a `dcommit` is in progress, although that may work if you're always pushing out your `HEAD` commit and it goes cleanly.

When `HEAD` is being `dcommit`d, the process ends with doing `git reset --mixed` against the new commit which reflects the current state of the svn repository. If you'd instead push some older commit, the process would end by attempting to rebase your current branch on top of the new commit that was fetched from svn; this would abort if there are uncommitted changes.

You're also likely to have problems if `dcommit` would run into a conflict while pushing the changes to svn, which you would then need to resolve manually. Having unrelated changes in the working tree is likely to mess this up.

You could create a separate clone of your `git svn` repository, do all your actual work there, and use the `git svn` repository only for interacting with the svn repository. Then it would of course be safe to make any changes in your working repository while the other one was processing a `dcommit` operation. But you would, of course, need to be pushing and/or pulling commits between those repositories.

Comment: Well, copying isn't an option since the initial problem of *big* repository means I'll have to wait an hour or so for copying to compelete :)

Comment: I highly doubt that doing a local clone would take anywhere near that long. If you're using a filesystem that supports hard links it wouldn't even copy much of the repository data, just create hard links to the pack files.

Comment: It's Windows. Also, it's 30k files, so it takes maybe even more time to copy.